# Linkedin/Facebook post box like

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I would like to create an post box similar to linkedin's and facebook's; when something is pasted in it, if a URL is detected in it, then a thumbnail is created.

My 2 questions are:
* Does such a ready-made component exist already? I searched a lot but couldn't come across this
* If I am to make it myself, what I don't get is how does facebook and linkedin manage to detect the **right image** to grab and thumbnail. It does not seem like it takes a random image, if you have an article with a heading image for example, they are able to capture it... I am wondering if you would to do it, what kind of approach would you follow ? Maybe: Grab the page, parse images, take the biggest (but this seems too much to process)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the major implementors of this sort of functionality respect certain meta-tags (certainly Facebook, Google+, LinkedIn), before looking for a default image.  If you specify the og:image meta tag, that will be used in preference to anything else.  May have changed recently, but in absence of that tag, FB used to use the first image on the page, and has a sort of carousel control that lets the person who is sharing select from the others on the page, in order that they're found in the scrape.

More details from FB are found here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters)

If I wanted to implement the same functionality, I'd probably take that same approach.  Look first for the image described in the og:image meta tag, and if there isn't one specified (or it's a broken link), select either the first image found, or display a list of found images to the user (perhaps with something to limit only to images that are large enough not to be icons - so larger than 64x64px or something)

Comment: Thanks so much Chris ! Clear enough !